# ListBox com dados JSON - Delphi mobile

Tags: json, delphi, mobile

Tenho esses dados `JSON` que retorna de uma consulta webservice:

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "usuario":"teste",
    "senha":"teste",
    "chave":"d59876jh",
    "email":"prestoexpress@live.com"
}]
```

Preciso popular os Itens de um `ListBox` com eles.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Só para eu entender melhor, você está consumindo os dados de um WebService, precisa popular o ListBox no Mobile com o retorno dos dados do WebService, você já fez a conexão Mobile via WebService?... se sim, sugiro pesquisar sobre RESTClient, RESTResponse e RESTRequest que são os componentes para receber esses dados.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf eu estou usando apenas um IdHTTP que faz uma consulta via GET e retorna esse JSON pois dessa forma eu nao utilizo REST apenas o retorno de uma URL passada pelo componente pois meu webservice é php mysql hospedado normalmente como um site.

Comment: Primeiro passo é encontrar um Framework para serializar/deserializar o JSON: Eu sugiro o https://bitbucket.org/soundvibe/delphi-oop/src. Assim que tiver decidido por algum, seguimos com os exemplos.

Comment: @VictorZanella eu ja criei o webservice php ele responde direitinho da forma como coloquei o JSON acima. Testei em um TMemo e tudo certinho com os pares etc. To apanhando na parte mais fácil teoricamente que seria popular o listBox com os dados obtidos.

Comment: O que eu quis dizer, é que é mais fácil, você achar uma lib para ler o JSON no Delphi. É muito mais fácil voce deserializar o JSON em uma lista de objetos, e trabalhar com ela, do que ficar percorrendo uma string.

Comment: Nessa caso, se um dia você precisar mandar algo da aplicação para seu webapp, vai facilitar também. Se estiver de acordo, posso montar um exemplo com a lib

Comment: @EzequielTavares, conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf acabei abandonando o Delphi para aplicações móbiles estou usando PHONEGAP que me suepreendeu com a extrema simplicidade de desenvolver mobile. abraço

Answer (score -1):

Se tens o retorno dos dados, vou colocar um exemplo de como popular um ListBox, mas percebi que tem vários dados de um usuário por exemplo, não era melhor usar o ListView?...

```
var
  i: Integer;
  oListBoxItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
  for i := 0 to 5-1 do
  begin
    oListBoxItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
    oListBoxItem.Text := 'Stack';
    oListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory(1);
    ListBox1.AddObject(oListBoxItem);
  end;
  ListBox1.EndUpdate;
end;
```